# socket.io doesn't persist connections

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following code in my app module.

```
var socket_io = require( 'socket.io' );
const io = socket_io();
io.on( "connection", function( socket ) {   
    console.log(io.sockets.connected[socket.id]); 
}
```

This returns a socket.

The following function in my app module returns undefined:

```
var emit_to_socket = function (id) {
    console.log(io.sockets.connected[id]);
}
```

When I use io.emit() the client receives the message; however the message is broadcasted to all clients:

```
 var emit_to_socket = function (id) {
    io.emit('message');
 }
```

I need to know how to send messages to a specific socket.

Comment: You don't show us how you call `emit_to_socket(id)`.  You should use `io.to(id)` and that will work as long as the `id` value is valid and current.  So, we'd have to see where you're getting that id from and how you're using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
socket.to(<desired_socket_id>).emit('message')
```

Below is the example from documentation: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-to-room

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('say to someone', (id, msg) => {
    // send a private message to the socket with the given id
    socket.to(id).emit('my message', msg);
  });
});
```